# Custom modal login php form receives 404 resource not found error

Tags: php

I'm working on a custom PHP, modal login form.  When I click the Login button, I receive the 404 resource not found, being my PHP file that handles the authentication.

The two files are here:

**action_page.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $name = 'user1';
    $pwd = 'home';

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     // get vars
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      if ($username == $name and $password == $pwd){
          redirect('http://www.mden.com');
      } else {
          redirect('http://www.youtube.com');
      }

  } else {
      redirect('login.html');
  }
?>
```

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        form {
            border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
        }

        input[type=text], input[type=password] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 100%;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        .cancelbtn {
            width: auto;
            padding: 10px 18px;
            background-color: #f44336;
        }

        .container {
            padding: 16px;
        }

        span.psw {
            float: right;
            padding-top: 16px;
        }

        /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
        @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
            span.psw {
               display: block;
               float: none;
            }
            .cancelbtn {
               width: 100%;
            }
        }

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.4);
            padding-top: 60px;
        }

        /* Modal Content/Box */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: 5px auto;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 20%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            /* Position it in the top right corner outside of the modal */
            position: absolute;
            right: 25px;
            top: 0;
            color: white;
            font-size: 35px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        /* Close button on hover */
        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        /* Add Zoom Animation */
        .animate {
            -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
            animation: animatezoom 0.6s
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
            from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
            to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
        }

        @keyframes animatezoom {
            from {transform: scale(0)} 
            to {transform: scale(1)}
        }
    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Button to open the modal login form -->
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Login</button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="id01" class="modal">
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

        <!-- Modal Content -->
        <form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action="/action_page.php">
            <!-- No Avatar!!! -->

            <!-- Login Info -->
            <div class="container">
                <label><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required><br /><br />

                <label><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required><br /><br />
                <button name="do_login" type="submit">Login</button>

            </div>

            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">

                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div> 

    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's better if you post your code here rather than Pastebin that allow other StackOverflow user to just be on site and resolve your query quickly

Answer (score 0):

The file path used in your form's action is correct?
Try remove the `"/"` from `action="/action_page.php"` if `action_page.php`  stay on same directory.

Comment: Hello.  Initially I didn't have the "/"  Both files are in the same folder.